# Php AJAX not working in conjunction with my php script and mysql

Tags: php, ajax

So here I am posting my first PHP function that I am proud of but I just recently learned about AJAX and wanted to test it out. Unfortunately I can't get it to work.

---

**My experience:** PHP (3 weeks). CSS3, HTML, Basic Javascript.

---

**My Problem:** Getting AJAX to work. I want ajax to get my data from the php file which gets the votes from my test server (Xampp) database. So each time the user clicks on good or bad AJAX should display the new results without refreshing the page. The issue is however that: A) My if statements work by checking isset($_POST) which wont work anymore if I call by AJAX. B) Preventing refresh. C) Making AJAX update after every click. I know im nearly there, im just missing something and I dont know exactly what it is to be honest.

---

**What I tried:** Checked my database connection. Checked if my php code worked without ajax and it does perfectly fine (I am just displaying half of the functionality here, a lite version, for the sake of simplicity). Tried to change submit to button. Cache clearing. Jquery is in the head of my document and the path is correct. Watched tutorials and read the documentation but I am just not heading anywhere, probably due to lack of experience.

Edit: Sessions and everything php works fine. I my session start and database connection are included on the very top.

---

**Summary:** How do I fix this ajax so that it always updates my numbers?

---

Let me know if you want me to explain parts of my php code. Im willing to comment the parts if neccesary.

---

**JQUERY / AJAX CODE**

```
function vote() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "php/core/voting_system.php",
            type: "POST",           
            dataType: 'html'
        });

        request.done(function(vote_sum) {
            $("#votes").html(vote_sum);         
        });
}
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id='votes'></div>

<form id="good" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="good" onclick="vote()" value="+">
</form>

<form id="bad" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="bad" onclick="vote()" value="-">
</form>
```

Comment: Because you're checking for specific things in the POST array and your AJAX hasn't passed anything to the PHP, you're not getting a result. [Have a look at this.](http://jayblanchard.net/putting_it_all_together.html)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think I even remove the if statements once. Result was the same. It updated once but not the second time.

Comment: These statements, `isset($_POST['bad']` and `isset($_POST['good']` will *never* process because you're not sending anything via AJAX to the PHP script. You have no `data:` property in your AJAX request. [Open your browser's console to see what is going on.](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: It also looks like you're not starting the session in your PHP.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I actually did via include. Session(start) is the first thing I set up. I tested all of the php side of the code and it works.

Comment: @JayBlanchard do you have an idea how I could get the data properly and make this work?

Comment: @Asperger if you want to up-vote or down-vote you should send it in your Ajax request.for example if user clicks up-vote the function for up-vote should run and if the user clicks the down-vote the function for down-vote should run.and in each function you should send the type of vote as Ajax `data` and check for it in your PHP

Comment: @Mr.NaViD edited my post with an example of how I interpreted your comment. Maybe you could show me an example if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML you don't need `<form>`, you are doing it with `AJAX`, right?

```
<div id='votes'></div>
<button onclick="vote('good');">+</button>
<button onclick="vote('bad');">-</button>
```

In JavaScript, it is easier to use `post` rather than `ajax` function

```
function vote(gb) {
  $.post("php/core/voting_system.php", { vote: gb }, function(vote_sum) {
    $("#votes").html(vote_sum);         
  });
}
```

In PHP, extract the vote and use it as needed (add validation/sanitation):

```
$vote = $_POST['vote']; // either 'good', or 'bad'
// do what you need with it
```

Comment: Should I use prepared statements?

Comment: Oh and why do all tutorials do the ajax method. Will I still be able to see the updated votes every time I click on bad or good?

Comment: You certainly could, but you don't have too. Just make sure you avoid mysql_* functions and instead use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: Sure you could. `post`, `get`, `load`, and `getJSON` all use `ajax` internally, but their syntax is easier to work with.

Comment: Oh I see, later I will try to understand what is "under the hood". Is jquery faster in the long term due to less code repetition? Oh and I use mysqli functions. I will use PDO in the future for OOP.

Comment: by the way, there are 3 or 4 answers here. Im not entirely sure which one to choose! Could need some feedback :)

Comment: All three answers are correct. It is a mater of taste then. But the newer users would certainly enjoy the gratification of having their answer accepted more! So there you go ;)

Comment: Like so within my php file?  if ($vote = $_POST['good']){
  voting_system ();
  }

Comment: No, what is being sent to the server is not in *good* or *bad* **key**. The key is `vote` and its value would be either `good` or `bad`.

Comment: Indeed I just noticed that you passed it db as a parameter in your function. Smart. The vote_sum is empty though. The script works I tried it with a simple echo on variable $vote. - gives bad and + gives good. vote_sum fails to do so however. It seems it cant fetch the information from my database, or at least that is what I believe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88407/discussion-between-asperger-and-majid-fouladpour).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR version:**

You didn't include a data field inside your `$.ajax` call. Also, your script isn't checking which button was pressed.

**The long version**

When you're performing your `$.ajax` call, you fail to attach any data to the request. This can be done easily like so:

```
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: ...someJSONData...
  });
```

Usually, you're going to want to pass JSON to anything, because it can contain complex object structures that you would usually want to communicate between the client and the server. You're clearly not in this example, but if you're trying to learn this stuff, it's better to start off the right way.

Both javascript and php make using the JSON format extremely easy: JS JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse(), PHP json_encode() and json_decode().

```
function vote(e) {
  // e.target.id stores the id of the button that was clicked
  var data = {vote: e.target.id}

  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    ... callbacks and other properties ...
  });
}

document.getElementById("good").addEventListener("click", vote);
document.getElementById("bad").addEventListener("click", vote);
```

This would be a simple example of how you could solve your problem. If you did a simple `var_dump` in your php script after running the data through `json_decode()` you would get a nice associative array:

```
[
  'data' => 'good',
]
```

I hope this illustrates how easy it is to pass data around in this format.

Also notice I defined the event handlers in the javascript. This is generally better, because you keep all your javascript in one place and it makes things cleaner and easier to debug.

Comment: I will read it through. Majid Fouladpours method is very short but yours seems very attractive as well. What do you say? I like the way you explain things

Comment: It may seem long and intimidating at first, when you're first learning about it, and this is not the simplest solution for this particular example, but it scales well when you're trying to do more complex things, which I'm sure you'll run into if you do any more webdev :)

Comment: do I need a json file in order to use your ajax method? I never worked with json files before.

Comment: No, you can convert javascript objects and arrays to a JSON string using the methods I mentioned above, then you can send that in the data field of your ajax request. Your php script can the read that string from the POST fields and decode it, and you've got a nice associative array. Vice versa works as well of course. No files needed. You can use files, but for a simple server client request there's no need for files.

Comment: I noticed you did not specify an url to the php file, is there a reason or did you leave those parts out for the sake of simplicity?

Comment: I left that out because otherwise my answer would be even longer. You need that field of course otherwise your script wouldn't know where to send the request.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/eayybg7g/  let me know if I misinterpreted something. Also why did you add the value of $data in } brackets?

Comment: Well yes, sort of like that. You misplaced the done callback, so that's invalid javascript. I put the data into braces so that I put it into a javascript object, so you get that nice key value pair in the php associative array. That way, you can stick more things into the object you're sending so that you can pass more data to the server: An updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eayybg7g/1/

Comment: Im so thankful for your time. I really appreciate this you know. Usually people post solutions but dont explain them well. As someone eager to learn best practice coding your info is very valuable and spares me time filtering out good tutorials from bad when doing searches on this topic.

Comment: In your jsfiddle, which way do you prefer? 1 or 2?

Comment: No problem, I'm just happy to help. When I use jquery, I usually prefer the first method I put there, because to me it makes sense that the request callbacks should be part of the request. But that's purely personal preference. Use whichever way seems cleaner to you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Like Jay said you're not sending POST data through the AJAX. You also need to echo your results from PHP.

```
function vote(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
         url: "php/core/voting_system.php",
         type: "POST",           
         dataType: 'html',
         data: 'bad='+$('input[name="bad"]').val()+'&good='+$('input[name="good"]').val(),
         success: function(data){
             var votes = $("#votes").val().empty();
             $("#votes").html(data+votes);
         }
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Could you comment your code? Especially the data part.

Comment: You have events for your ajax request like beforesend, complete, success, etc... Success accepts three parameters: data (any type), textStatus (404, 302, etc) and the jqXHR object.

What i did there was just use the data parameter to append (in this case add) the result to the div with id votes. Data can be anything you want, if you need an array you need to json_encode it in your PHP function and return it to the ajax with and echo.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/